# Edit was approved by... no one? Not even Community♦?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

See [this approved suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2481216#./2481216?&_suid=13734696686890023609686670714447).

I didn't like the fact that the suggested edit removed the "useless code and comments", and was going to reject the edit.  But it got approved.

So I was going to yell at whomever approved it and then roll it back.  Except...

[image]

No one approved the edit?  Not even Community♦?  I was under the impression that sometimes Community♦ would auto-reject or auto-approve an edit, but at least would still be listed as the Reviewer.  Am I missing something?

**2013-07-30 update**:

It [just happened again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2620460#./2620460?&_suid=13752168002230549324418664391), how spooky.  I know it's not *hurting* anything, but I'm genuinely curious how this is happening, since it doesn't seem to be an isolated case.

Comment: By _whom_, not by _who_. It even sounds wrong. (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: @JanDvorak - you know, it didn't sound right :P

Comment: It was obviously a reverse audit; the edit was real but the approvers were fake.

Comment: Eeek. Where's Oded when you need him?

Comment: Could it have been approved by the OP?

Comment: Possibly, but I was under the impression the OP would still be listed.  Since Meta is lower traffic, if someone here with less than 2000 rep wants to give me a heads-up, then edit one of my questions, I can try and approve it and see what happens, before anyone else reviews it.

Comment: Test edit to this post done.

Comment: @Joe - thanks, and check it out, I'm listed:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15841#./15841?&_suid=137365381213609661562983295985.  So either it's restricted to SO, it was a complete fluke, or there's some subtle nuance that I'm just not aware of.

Comment: I tried a Data.SE query relating to the above Suggested Edit, and I can't find the edit!  I'm perhaps not doing it properly, or maybe the SE table doesn't work properly... or maybe something's weird about this one.

Comment: Hmm, Data.SE isn't updated frequently enough to look at this yet, I guess.  Oh well.

Comment: Maybe upgrade this to a bug?

Comment: That's obviously a bug. I've seen thousands of suggested edits, it **always** show who approved/rejected, be it user or Community account.

Comment: Timeline: 15:17:24 posted; 15:20:18 proposed; 15:21:26 approved. My **guess**: the poster made an edit within the 5-minute window, clicking on the “edit” button after 15:20:18, and submitting his edit at 15:21:26. There's quite a bit of wonkiness regarding suggested edits concurrent with another edit, especially if that other edit involves the 5-minute window. If that's the case, you can't trust the diff: it's not what the suggestor proposed, it's the diff between the suggestion and the concurrently-edited version.

Comment: @Gilles - that's actually a really good guess, I'd buy that, except the OP would have clicked Edit *before* it was proposed @ 15:20:18, correct? Either way, super wonky.

Comment: I think someone dropped the table containing information about the approvers.

Answer (score 8):

I created a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/126711/155327) that shows the suggested edit for the first edit mentioned in the OP.  There are no votes for it when I look at the SuggestedEditVotes table.  There are votes for the other edit that user made, so it's nothing specific to the user.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/126731/approved-edits-with-no-votes) shows all of the edits that exist with no approvals but an approval date that is not null.  There seem to be a run of them at certain times - like 3/13 3:20:00 UTC - which suggests there's a database glitch or something like that where the table isn't properly updating.