# Edit was rejected without reviews?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have [suggested an edit on a post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2774639) on Stack Overflow by adding a tag, which was in my view helpful. It got rejected without any reviews. How can that be?

> [image]

**EDIT:**

Since this rejection is still maculating my edit ratio and this appears to be a Bug.
I still want to know in how far the awareness that this is a bug gets treat. 
And as I'm a victim of this bug can I get removed this "penalty"?

Comment: When the op of the question rejects your update, does it even say who did it? Could this be the scenario here?

Comment: Maybe a grace-period edit by the op?

Comment: Nope, there were no edits at all at the OP's question

Comment: The thing about grace-period edits is that they aren't listed, so one might have happened without any indication

Comment: @StephenTG But the question wasn't that big at all and i can see there is no change between the text i eddited and the text there is now

Comment: @Zaibis You might not notice something like a one letter typo in a word.

Comment: @StephenTG If that's the case it *should* mark the edit as rejected by "community".  That's what normally happens with edits rejected because of a conflicting edit.

Comment: Hum, and then i just would get an reject, because the author changed 1 letter:O

Comment: @Servy Ok, didn't remember exactly what got labelled under community. Just throwing out possible ideas

Comment: @Zaibis That's certainly a possibility.  If that is the case though, it would still be a bug as it should mark the edit as rejected by community.

Comment: @StephenTG That may very well be what happened, but if it is, it would be a display bug, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: I could have sworn I saw this issue before, but no sign of a dup.  Either it was deleted, I'm mistaken, or the previous issue did not use common terminology

Comment: I saw that edit and tried to approve it but failed as there was the rejection

Comment: I was able to find [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188242), which is the same thing except in the Approve state.

Comment: My last guess is that your edit was so terrible, the source code of the website knew to reject immediately.

Comment: I just added a tag "undefined-behaviour" because the question was about "is this undefined behaviour or not?" and the only tag was "c" so i guess it wasn't that horrible ^^

Comment: @animuson that's the one I remembered.  Forgot it was an approval, not a rejection.  Probably the same bug causing it?

Comment: Your edit was 2 minutes and 22 seconds after the OP posted, and was rejected 34 seconds after you posted, so still well within the edit grace period for the OP. My guess is the same as Gilles comment on the question linked by animuson - The diff is showing the current version versus your suggestion, not the original versus yours, and the grace period edit dropped your suggestion into an unattributed reject. I'm guessing the difference in approve vs reject has to do with what the OP selected when doing their post suggestion grace period edit.

Comment: @jball likely the case, but still a bug as Community is supposed to reject these posts.

Comment: So just for me to notify: the point of rejection is fine, but that there is not shown rejected by who is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't happen again. As Oded wrote [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196315/152859):

> There was a race condition that caused one of our scheduled tasks to invalidate suggested edits that shouldn't have been invalidated.

And he fixed the bug causing this. (it affected only users with 500-2000 reputation points who once could perform the tag edit without peer review)

Worth to mention that suggested edits rejected by Community user ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/458355)) are [no longer counted towards the suggested edit ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/152859). (dunno about the race condition rejection, probably it did count)

Comment: You are absolutly missing my problem, my problem is that my Suggestion got rejected without any review, There wasn't even the community as reviewer it self. Or am I getting wrong you?!

Comment: @Zaibis it was indeed a bug, it is fixed now. What else do you want?

Comment: @Zaibis if you mean add some explanation in the suggested edit page then you should make it into a feature request, but be aware there is [already such feature request pending](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153403/152859).

Comment: No what I mean is, when I suggested the edit it just said as on the screenshot: "Edit rejected 11min ago:" and there just where blank. there were not the community not any user or something else. so it got as the title says rejected without ANY review, not rejected as grace edit by community.

Comment: @Zaibis right but it won't happen again, so I still miss your point/request. What's done is done, if you mean adding text explaining the rejection reason see my previous comment.

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, Your statement was that the bug of invalidate rejects by community got fixed, wasn't it? But my question wasn't to the community reject, as i hadn't even a reject by community.

Comment: @Zaibis No, the Community user still reject edits due to conflicts with other edits and it's not a bug. Your specific case is different and is not related to edit conflict.

Comment: I guess we have a communication problem..... could you please tell me what my problem is in your words? so that i can see you got me right?!

Comment: @Zaibis your specific case was very rare. It happened only for tag  edits and only for 500-2000 rep users. When happening, nobody rejected the edit it just "vaporized" hence no name shown below the "rejected". **This specific bug is solved and fixed**. In addition to this, there are many cases when Community user account "reject" edits [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/458355) but that's **not a bug** and whole different story. Hope it's clear now, as I can't explain any better. :)

Comment: Ohkay, thanks. So I just got you wrong.

Comment: Aditionaly, do i have a way to get this rejection removed from my ratio?

Comment: @Zaibis you suggested many more edits after that "incident" and all approved as far as I could see, so that rejection is now meaningless. The edit ban algorithm is taking only X recent rejections. If you mean change "and 2 edit suggestions rejected" to "and 1 edit suggestion rejected" then I fear it's not possible, but it's really not a big deal nobody will take it against you.

Comment: Hahaha ok thats sad. I dreamed to keep it jsut to 1. But nevermind, thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Zaibis sure thing, happy editing! :-)