# Trying to add new tag (1.5K user) results in instant "This item is no longer reviewable"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, suggested-edits

I just reached 1500 rep last night on Stack Overflow, and I thought it would be nice to create a tag for our project "QtSerialPort".

Having read the text on the url below, I am about to go to the corresponding existing questions, to add yet another tag to them.

http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-September/012988.html

This is one of those threads where the new tag could fit nicely:

[Qt 4.7 QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo : No Such file or Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442672/qt-4-7-qtserialport-qserialportinfo-no-such-file-or-directory)

When I am trying to add the new tag without editing the body, or even the title, I am not getting any usual feedback about the tag request being received, and does not show up for me  in the desired post either. The new tag cannot be found for a tag search either.

As Anna Lear wrote it seems that the request for the edit became invalid automatically without any review right away for some reason. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2881129) you can find the url for the edit suggestion.

[Pops](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/pops) mentioned that in the chat room (Tavern on Meta) that this may be a bug, but not completely sure, so I am now bringing this up for clarification. Perhaps, the workaround could be to edit the body of the post if it contains issues, but there are posts where that is not the case. Is this somehow possible or is it a known bug? If the latter holds true, are there people working on fixing it?

Apologies, if this is a duplicated post. I have not found any existing one with a quick search. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's a bug, happening because the "Retag" privilege has been removed. This means that until you reach 2K reputation you can only suggest edits, and looks like new tags can't be "suggested". Either such option should be added, or more likely the "Create Tags" privilege better be changed to 2K rep, along with full edits.

Comment: Here's a link to the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2881129). It looks like it just got invalidated right away without any actions from other users, so it probably is a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a race condition that caused one of our scheduled tasks to invalidate suggested edits that shouldn't have been invalidated.

In this case, you were simply unlucky with timing - trying *again* would have resulted in success.

This has been fixed for the next release.

Comment: So what will happen now when 1.5K user suggests new tag?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - the tag will be created, and the change is a suggested edit. The bug is one of timing and he was simply unlucky here. I'd be really surprised if he were able to reproduce it.

Comment: I have not tried it since I got the necessary reputation in the meantime to edit the posts myself, but thank you for your effort!